# Undefined value returned - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am receiving a value from a function to pass to a method in a class. When I pass the value returned from the function in web.js, it returns undefined in my **shopifyStore** class. What could be the reason and how I could solve this ?

PS: Beginner with javascript

**web.js**

```
window.shopify.findName({}, function(items) {  
   var shopify = items;

   console.log(items); //this returns the value 
   pushValue(items); 
});

export function pushValue(items) { return items; }
```

**component**

```
import * as shopifyHelper from '/web.js';

class shopifyStore extends HTMLElement {
   constructor() {
      super();
   }

   getItemCount() {
      console.log(shopifyHelper.pushValue()) // this returns undefined
   }
}
```

Comment: Try `export default pushValue;`
And import it as `import { pushValue } from './web.js';`

Comment: @TrishantPahwa, can you explain how different your answer is, please ?

Comment: I guess the way your are exporting and importing the function is incorrect.

Comment: @TrishantPahwa returns undefined

Comment: Might need to see your log. Do you have discord?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should promisify the callback of `window.shopify.findName` method. Rework your `pushValue` function:

```
export function pushValue(items) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      window.shopify.findName({}, items => resolve(items));
   })
}
```

and call it like this:

```
async getItemCount() {
   console.log(await shopifyHelper.pushValue());
}
```

or:

```
getItemCount() {
   shopifyHelper.pushValue().then(items => console.log(items));
}
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) you can read more about async functions.
And [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) you can read more about promises.

Comment: That was only a typo:). It actually returns undefined because the value is not ready yet. (callback).

Comment: You have any help ? I am just starting with JS

Comment: Thanks. you are the best